# how to store the date result into database which is get from TimeZone in mvc2

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-2, timezone

I converted the date time using **TimeZoneInfo** in mvc2.

**In my controller:**

```
DateTime updatedDate = DateTime.Now;
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(updatedDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "India Standard Time").ToString();
```

I want to assign the value **timeZone** into

```
item.updateddate=timeZone;
```

But it is showing an error. How to assing the values? I am new to this....

Comment: What is the error? This sounds like the type of Item.UpdateDate isn't the same as the timeZone variable.

Comment: it shows line error.."Cannot Implicitly convert type string to system.datetime. this is the error.

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of repeatedly opening a nee question for the same item.

Answer (score 0):

As I assumed your error is because you are trying to convert a string to a date time. What you need to do is use something like DateTime.ParseExact.

Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I find the issue because of you. var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(updatedDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "India Standard Time");

Comment: Ahh, you were converting the return value to a string. That would have caused your problem!